# sleep() causes program to hang indefinitely

Tags: python, sleep

I'm working on a mail sending python script in Linux.

I can send 10 messages, then need to wait 5 - 10 minutes before sending again.

I am executing the following code inside of a `while()` loop.

```
#Pausing so the MailServer doesn't complain
delay = randint(300,600)
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(current_time + " sleeping " + str(timedelta(seconds=delay)))
sleep(delay)
```

This causes the program to hang whether it is at the beginning of the loop or end.

While stepping through with `pdb`, I can't detect the issue.

I am *not* using threading (just because I haven't learned how yet).

I'm open to ideas.

Comment: you don't have any loop in your code. the code you posted will execute once and finish

Comment: Please create a [mre]